# Polymer Web apps Home screen for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, polymer, progressive-web-apps

I have a polymer web app that can be easily added to the Home Screen of an Android device.But I am not getting any way to add home screen for ios.

In google developer blog I find one post where they told it's not possible for ios.This post is now backdated.I believe there have some way to add home screen for ios/iPhone in 2017 :)
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen

Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.
[image]

> This feature I am looking for ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not support Progressive Web Application features yet....

They have supported an Add to Home Screen Experience since the iPhone was first released. You need the touch icons referenced in the previous answer.

You still need to manually prompt the user to add to the home screen. I have used Spinnelli's library to help, http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.I will try it and let you know